# PHP.Почему не получается использовать в консольном скрипте переменную полученую через fgets(STDIN)?

Tags: php, консоль, php7.2

Есть такой скрипт.среда выполнения PHP-7.2, ос - ubuntu 18

```
$CONFIGS = [
    'y' => 'yii2-config',
    'h' => 'html-config',
    'w' => 'wordpress-config'
];

foreach ( $CONFIGS as $key => $value ) {
    echo $key . ' - ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
$choice = fgets(STDIN);
echo $choice;
print_r($CONFIGS);
echo $CONFIGS['y'].PHP_EOL;
echo $CONFIGS[$choice];
```

Запускаю в консоли.в выводе имею:

```
alexey@alexey-K54L:~/www/creator$ php test.php  
y - yii2-config  
h - html-config  
w - wordpress-config  
y  
y  
Array  
(  
   [y] => yii2-config  
   [h] => html-config  
   [w] => wordpress-config  
)  
yii2-config  
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: y  
in /home/alexey/www/creator/test.php on line 16
```

Почему `Undefined index: y`. Что не так то?

Comment: кодировка файла не так, не совпадает с консольной

Comment: Спасибо)  как решение стал использовать readline() и все заработало

Comment: @teran кодировка ни при чем. Обратите внимание, что в выводе консоли после `y` переносится строка. `fgets(STDIN)` читает с консоли не `y`, а `y\n` (с кодом перевода строки). После ввода надо делать `trim($choice)`